# Doubts regarding config_setting with Bazel

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to understand `config_setting` for detecting the underlying platform and had some doubts. Could you help me clarify them?

1. What is the difference between `x64_windows` and `x64_windows_(msvc|msys)` cpus? If I create config_setting's for all of them, will only one of them trigger? Should I just ignore `x64_windows`?
2. To detect Windows, what is the recommended way? Currently I'm doing:

   ```
   config_setting(
       name = "windows",
       values = {"crosstool_top": "//crosstools/windows"},
   )

   config_setting(
       name = "windows_msvc",
       values = {
           "crosstool_top": "//crosstools/windows",
           "cpu": "x64_windows_msvc",
       },
   )

   config_setting(
       name = "windows_msys",
       values = {
           "crosstool_top": "//crosstools/windows",
           "cpu": "x64_windows_msys",
       },
   )
   ```

   By using this I want to use `:windows` to match *all* Windows versions and `:windows_msvc`, for example, to match only MSVC. Is this the best way to do it?
3. What is the difference between `darwin` and `darwin_x86_64` cpus? I know they match macOS, but do I need to always specify both when selecting something for macOS? If not, is there a better way to detect macOS with only one `config_setting`? Like using `//crosstools` with Windows?
4. How do detect Linux? I know you can detect the operating systems you care about first and then use `//conditions:default`, but it'd be nice to have a way to detect specifically Linux and not leave it as the default.
5. What are `k8`, `piii`, etc? Is there any documentation somewhere describing all the possible cpu values and what they mean?
6. If I wanted to use `//crosstools` to detect each platform, is there somewhere I can look up all available crosstools?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great questions, all. Let me tackle them one by one:

1. `--cpu=x64_windows_msys` triggers the C++ toolchain that relies on MSYS/Cygwin. `--cpu=x64_windows_msvc` triggers the Windows-native (MSVC) toolchain. `-cpu=x64_windows` triggers the default, which is still MSYS but [being converted](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2627) to MSVC.

   Which ones you want to support is up to you, but it's probably safest to support all for generality (and if one is just an alias for the other it doesn't require very complicated logic).

   Only one `config_setting` can trigger at a time.
2. Unless you'e using a custom `-crosstool_top=` flag to specify Windows builds, you'll probably want to trigger on `--cpu`, e.g:

   ```
   config_setting(
       name = "windows",
       values = {"cpu": "x64_windows"}
   ```

   There's not a great way now to define *all* Windows. This is a current deficiency in Bazel's ability to recognize *platforms*, which settings like `--cpu` and `--crosstool_top` don't quite model the right way. [Ongoing work](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2219) to create a first-class concept of platform will provide the best solution to what you want. But for now `--cpu` is probably your best option.
3. This would basically be the same story as Windows. But to my knowledge there's only `darwin` for default crosstools, no `darwin_x86_64`.
4. For the time being it's probably best to use the `//conditions:default` approach you'd rather not do. Once first-class platforms are available that'll give you the fidelity you want.
5. `k8` and `piii` are pseudonyms for 86 64-bit and 32-bit CPUs, respectively. They also tend to be associated with "Linux" by convention, although this is not a guaranteed 1-1 match.

   There is no definitive set of "all possible CPU values". Basically, `--cpu` is just a string that gets resolved in CROSSTOOL files to toolchains with identifiers that match that string. This allows you to write new CROSSTOOL files for new CPU types you want to encode yourself. So the exact set of available CPUs depends on who's using Bazel and how they have their workspace set up.
6. For the same reasons as 5., there is no definitive list. See Bazel's github `tools/` directory for references to defaults.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanations! I understand how the feature works much better now.

Comment: I guess I'll wait for when the new platform feature is released to start thinking about making my build multiplatform. Thanks for that issue link, I did not see it when I searched the issues list. It'll help a lot.